# Interpret sentence and convert into their corresponding format

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, nlp

There are some formats of inputs and their corresponding outputs

```
1. 7 years 10 months  ---> YRS:7 MNHS:10
2. 7 kgs 10 grms      ---> KGS:7 GRMS:10
3. 7 kilograms 10 grams  ---> KGS:7 GRMS:10
4. 7 thousand 9 hundread ---> 7900
5. seven years ten months --> YRS:7 MNHS:10 
6. seven kgs ten grms     ---> KGS:7 GRMS:10
7. triple seven double five  --> 77755
```

**I wrote separate modules for all by storing informations in **HashMap**. And it is working fine.**

Then I need to write one main module in which input is one sentence(utterance), and I need to replace all above substrings into corresponding substring output.

**For example**,

**Input** :- Dial number triple eight triple four three nine eight.

**Output** :- Dial number 888444398.

and many such utterances.

**My doubts :-**

1. I used numbers of HashMap for smaller modules to store meaning of keys, just like - triple means 3 times, double means 2 times and all. But this has limitation that if I need to add anything I have to add that entry in HashMap. **Suggest some good technique for this.**
2. I am confused in main module, how to extract useful substring given in above examples from given utterances. **So suggest some good technique for this also.**

Project Lanuguage : Java.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Illinos Quantifier package:

http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Quantifier

http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/quantities/results.php

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use some kind of [formal grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser). Just doing design of a grammar can clear a view of the problem. In the most simple case your grammar could look like:

```
    STRING -> "" | STRING MEASUREMENT | STRING NUMBER | STRING WORD
    MEASUREMENT -> NUMBER UNITS
    UNITS -> kgs | grms | years | months | ...
    NUMBER -> THOUSAND HUNDRED NUMBER_BELOW_HUNDRED | THOUSAND HUNDRED
    THOUSAND -> "" | NUMBER_BELOW_HUNDRED thousand
    HUNDRED -> "" | NUMBER_BELOW_HUNDRED hundred
    NUMBER_BELOW_HUNDRED -> one | two | three | ... | ninety nine | 99 | 98 | ... | 1
    WORD -> /* all other */
```

You can write a parser by yourself (in this case it seems to be pretty easy) or use a ready solution like Bison/Flex.

The usual alternative for your HashMaps are [configuration files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file).